# Application Insights data sampling

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have an Azure Function linked with Application Insights. I log in AppInsights several business data and I can have a lot of instances of my function running during a short period of time.

I read the [documentation of Data Sampling in AppInsights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-sampling) and I want to know: Can I lose data because of this data sampling algorithm?

Answer (score 8):

*I want to know if I can lose data because of this data sampling algorithm?* -> Yes, that is the whole point of sampling:

> Sampling retains 1 in n records and **discards** the rest. For example, it might retain 1 in 5 events, a sampling rate of 20%.

If all data is critical for your logging/analysis purposes you should not apply sampling, or at least limit it.

There should be enough material in the link of your question to tell you how to enable/disable sampling and how to check whether it is applies currently.

Note that metrics by default are not sampled:

> Application Insights does not sample metrics and sessions telemetry types

Comment: In my App Insight configuration, I have this setting: "Select the fraction of data received from your app that the Application Insights service will retain using ingestion sampling:: All data (100%)" which means if I'm right that I will never lose any data, right?

Answer (score 4):

Regarding App Insights Sampling for Azure Functions [from the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#configure-sampling):

> "Application Insights has a sampling feature that can protect you from
>   producing too much telemetry data at times of peak load. When the
>   number of telemetry items exceeds a specified rate, Application
>   Insights starts to randomly ignore some of the incoming items. The
>   default setting for maximum number of items per second is 5. You can
>   configure sampling in host.json."

You can configure or disable sampling using the host.json

```
{
  "applicationInsights": {
    "sampling": {
      "isEnabled": true,
      "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond" : 5
    }
  }
}
```

If the logs are very critical, you also need to consider the [aggregation process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#configure-the-aggregator), which could lead to missing traces in re-cycles, etc.

HTH